# file modified date wrong on Android by 8 hours when transferring files with OSX

Tags: windows-7, macos, android, sd-card

I moved files to my desktop in OSX from an sd card and then to another sd card.

I then put that SD card into my android phone and the last modified date is off by 8 hours on all photos.

The modified date displays correct on OSX, Windows and a different android phone.

Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: What time zone are you in?  GMT+8 or GMT-8 (PST) perhaps?

Comment: I am in New York, the same SD card on another Android phone looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

SD card uses FAT filesystem , FAT timestamps are not referenced to any time zone.  android is linux and probably uses GMT timezone.  Windows FAT support probably does the same as MS-DOS and uses the local timezone.

1> set your windows system to run the hardware clock in GMT timezone

2> before inserting the SD card in your windows system set the local time-zone to GMT.

Confused yet? 
this page from Microsoft doesn't help much at all:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It seems you can also get wrong answers just by waiting. it seems windows doesn't handle retrospective timezone corrections well.

Comment: Haha totally confused because my other android phone is displaying the correct file times.

Comment: I pinpointed the problem, files copied with OSX are the issue.  Why only android is off makes no sense to me.